# How can i prevent to get next line in bootstrap panel right icon for the mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel

here is the image of desktop and mobile version - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLsF4.jpg)

But i want the print icon top right corner. I dont want it move next line.If screen size is reduced then i want [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt7DK.jpg) this.

code:

```
<h5 id="name">
<span class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></span>
   Name of Company Name of the company
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print pull-right"></span>
</h5>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making it as this:

```
 <h5 id="name">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <span class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></span>
        Name of Company Name of the company
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print pull-right"></span>
    </div>
</h5>
```

Comment: it should warp in row